# How to remove the first space when the condition is triggered?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the first space when the condition is triggered

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("in");
function hendler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
       inp.value = null;
       inp.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    }
}
inp.addEventListener('onblur', hendler, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" >
```

Comment: Every body thx  I solved the problem through event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `string.trim()` method 
example as your code you can use : - `inp.value.trim()` in 5th line of your given code 
the code below will work fine

```
  var inp = document.getElementById("in");
        function hendler() {
            inp.value = inp.value.trim();
        }
        inp.addEventListener('blur', hendler,false);
```

in `inp.addEventListener()` you have to use blur not onblur

Comment: thx, but how can I remove the first space in the input field when the condition is triggered

Comment: First:- get the value  and use string.trim() second:- assign the trimmed value back to input field ex:inp.value = inp.value.trim()

Comment: if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        inp.value = null;
        inp.value.trim();
    }
like this ? But first space is not remove

Comment: i have edited my answer you can see the code will work now

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `e.keyCode` with `blur` event. `e.keyCode` will be empty because you are not firing a key event. It will returns always `0`. You should change the logic of your function. Also, the event name is `blur`, not `onblur`. See the code below:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById( 'in' );

inp.addEventListener( 'blur', function() {
  var val = this.value
  if ( val && val.charCodeAt( 0 ) == 32 ) this.value = val.substr( 1 )
}, false )
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" >
```

And هf you want to delete all spaces from the beginning of the sentence, proceed as follows:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById( 'in' );

inp.addEventListener( 'blur', function() {
  var val = this.value
  if ( val && val.charCodeAt( 0 ) == 32 ) this.value = val.trim()
}, false )
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" >
```

Comment: Your answer is: `How to remove the first space`. and this function remove the first space only. Do not do this?

Comment: i want remove the first space before the word when it is removed when  condition work if i press space

Comment: Do you want to avoid inputting a space at the beginning of the word?